# How to extract all Ping Parameters in Perl

Tags: perl, ping

I am trying to ping around 100 hosts from a column in sql database
I am using the 
use Net::Ping; 
use Array::Average; modules

Is there an alternative such that i can extract the packet loss,rtt(min,max,avg) parameters directly from a perl script?

Here is my pseudo code

```
$p = Net::Ping->new('icmp');
$p->hires();
$host = "www.xyz.com";    
print "$host \n";       
@rtt= 0;
$j=0;
for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
   ($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($host, 5);# wait time 5
   if($ret){
      printf("$host [ip: $ip] $duration ms\n");
      $rtt[$i] = $duration;
   }


     else{
        $j++;

#$p->nack( $failed_ack_host );
}}
print " @rtt\n";
$rtt= average(@rtt);
print "The average rtt is $rtt \n";
$Packet_Loss = ((5-$j)/5)*100;
print "$Packet_Loss\%\n";
```

Comment: I think you'll be having to open an exec pipe to 'ping' directly and capture/parse the output if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

`Net::Ping' does not seem to return RTT, etc. You might try issuing the system ping command, and processing the results yourself:

```
$result = `ping -c 10 $host`;
```

...then parse `$result` for the fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation and source code, the `Net::Ping` module carries out just one "ping" each time you call the `ping()` method. It does not keep any internal "state" based on the success or otherwise of previous calls. The advantage of this approach is that it's simple and no-nonsense. However, if you want aggregated results, you're going to have to do them yourself, as you've discovered.

While it's tempting to call an external `ping` command, you need to be sure that's what you want: you gain not having to do some maths, but you then become more system-specific (not all systems have a `ping` command), you are dependent on some assumptions about what options to pass to the command and what format the output will be in, you've added the overhead of creating a new process, and you're running the risk that you may never get control back (some `ping` commands simply run until you interrupt them). Personally, I'd stick with the approach you're taking.

Also, in your particular code above, have a look at how you're storing your results. If the first three and last ping succeed, say, but the last-but-one doesn't, you're passing an array to `average()` with an undefined value, which is probably not what you want. I'd suggest something like this instead:

```
my @rtt;
my $attempts = 5;
foreach (1 .. $attempts) {
  my ($ret, $duration, $ip) = $p->ping($host, 5);  # timeout after 5 seconds
  if ($ret) {
     print "$host [ip: $ip] $duration ms\n";
     push @rtt, $duration;
  } else {
    $j++;
  }
}

⋮

if (@rtt) {
  my $rtt= average(@rtt);
  print "The average rtt is $rtt \n";
} else {
  print "No responses to ping\n";
}
```

This fixes one or two other corner cases as well.